# SharePoint 2013 InfoPath Form Library won't see .XML file as InfoPath Form

Tags: microsoft-infopath, sharepoint-2013

So I used the old SharePoint 2010 trick of using a designer workflow to create an InfoPath form via workflow. That piece is working great; however, my form library refuses to open the .xml InfoPath file that is created as an Infopath file. It just sees it as a .xml file. Even the icon is just an XML file icon.

When I download the file, I cannot open it in InfoPath either. In fact, it appears to be a blank xml file with 0 content. If I go back to the library itself, I can open up the template.xml as an InfoPath file no problem.

I am just out of ideas on what could possibly be causing this...

Few important details:

- SharePoint 2013 Online
- InfoPath 2013 (I have the client installed locally, but am able to
  view the form in the browser.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, but am not 100% sure I would consider a true solution. I ended up re-making my workflow as a SP2010 workflow instead of an SP2013. After I made that change, the library recognized the .xml file as an InfoPath.